# Gcm Notification data in activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I am using GCM Notification , i have done every setting regarding to receive the data , Gcm Notification is coming but when I click on the notification ,   it open but I got null in the intent.

**My chatscreenctivity**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.chatscreenctivity);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
        registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("broadmessage");  **//Hre i got Null**
        String sender_image=intent.getExtras().getString("sender_image");**//Hre i got Null**
        String sender_Name=intent.getExtras().getString("sender_name");
        mlistview=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        sendmessage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sendmeassage);
        sentext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_sent_msg);
        getActionBar().setTitle(sender_Name);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}





   Hre i got the value from gcm
         @Override
            protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
                String Message ="",image="",sendername="";
                String Broadscast = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
                if(Broadscast.equals("You have got login points!"))
                {
                    Message=Broadscast;
                    generateNotification(context, Message);
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                    JSONObject json=new JSONObject(Broadscast);
                    Message=json.getString("message");
                    image=json.getString("image");
                    sendername=json.getString("firstname")+" "+json.getString("lastname");

                    }
                    catch(JSONException e)
                    {

                    }
                    generateNotification(context, Broadscast);
                }
                displayMessage(context, Message);
                // notifies user

            }
```

Here is my custom notification and i am passing the value

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SlidingMenuActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.contentIntent=intent;

        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification); 


here is diaplaymessage in common utilites
   static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("broadmessage", message);
       intent.putExtra("sender_image", "fdgdfg");
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

Comment: If app crashes you have to show the `Logcat` trace so we can identify the `bug` easier

Comment: i have said that error is solved bt i got null value 
String message = intent.getExtras().getString("broadmessage");  **//Hre i got Null**
        String sender_image=intent.getExtras().getString("sender_image");**//Hre i got Null**
        String sender_Name=intent.getExtras().getString("sender_name"); here

Comment: please modify your question then

Comment: k i have changed , imy motive to explain deeply

Comment: try `getIntent().getStringExtra("broadmessage")`

Comment: it is showing null because you are not setting any data in notificationIntent. PendingIndtent is responsible for onClick of notification and notificationIntent don't have this value that's why you are getting null values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set Intent data in your notificationIntent like this

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SlidingMenuActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("broadmessage", message);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("sender_image", "fdgdfg");
    PendingIntent intent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.contentIntent=intent;

    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    // Play default notification sound
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    //notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

    // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```